# Como capturar dados do response error do axios quando usuário não possuir conexão?

Tags: javascript, react, axios

Estou utilizando o interceptor de responses do `axios` para tratar erros nas requisições.

Estou utilizando atualmente desta forma:

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3333'
});

api.interceptors.response.use(
  function (response) {
    // Qualquer status code que for entre o range 2xx ativa essa trigger
    // Mostra o toastr de success com mensagem vinda do backend
    ...
  }, function (error) {
    // Qualquer status code que for fora do range 2xx ativa essa trigger
    // Mostra o toastr de erro com mensagem vinda do backend
    ...
  }
```

Como podem ver, quando ocorre um erro no meu backend, ele entra no error e eu consigo capturar os dados do erro e mostrar um toastr acessando `error.response.data`. Porém como posso captar os dados de erro quando o usuário não possui conexão?

Tentei:

```
console.log(error)
```

É printado: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] 
É possível acessar apenas essa mensagem de erro? "Network Error" ou algo semelhante deste erro?

Tentei também:

```
console.log(error.response) // printa undefined
```

Comment: Tenta só com `console.log(error)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após pesquisar um tempo, encontrei essa [issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/383) no github do axios onde a mesma pergunta foi feita.

Como dito nas respostas, é impossível detectar erros de rede no navegador, portanto o axios responde com uma mensagem de erro genérica

> "Error: Network Error"

Onde a mesma não possui um status especifico, portanto, bastou fazer a seguinte verificação:

```
if (!error.status) {
    // Usuário não possui internet, mostra toastr de erro
}
```